# Cannot find module 'vuetify-loader/lib/plugin'

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

When I load vuetify via the vue-cli3, I get an error when i do npm run serve, saying there is a missing loader.

Docs etc and searches have come up blank.

This is a fresh project, no code loaded. Just following the instructions from the vuetify site.

Can anyone help?

Comment: I have the same issue were you able to figure it out?

Comment: figured it out. run npm cache clean --force

Answer (score 8):

I've got the same issues while creating new Vuetify app by [official guide](https://next.vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/quick-start#new-applications).

After adding vuetify: `vue add vuetify` 
The missing step was installing new npm dependencies with: `npm install`

Later I run `npm run serve` and it started succesfully. 
There is an issue in the documentation!

Answer (score 8):

Try to manually install the package:

```
npm install vuetify-loader -D
```

Answer (score 3):

you should check the vue-loader plugin path. in my case it is:

```
vue-loader/dist/plugin
```

Answer (score 2):

Run `npm cache clean --force`. It should clear your npm cache. 
For reference: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/19072#issuecomment-345555468

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. This whole thing worked out for me.

1. `vue create your-app`
2. `cd your-app`
3. `npm i --save-dev --no-optional vuetify-loader vue-cli-plugin sass node-sass sass-loader`
4. `npm i`
5. `vue add vuetify`

I know this looks redundant but it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when I cloned a repository and I installed the dependencies only on the master branch. When I  switched to a different branch (`git checkout different_branch`)  I forgot to install the dependencies there. So make sure you installed the dependencies before you launch the server.

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same problem. In my case it was caused by placing the file vue.config.js in the top-level-folder (next to package.json) instead of in the 'src' folder. 
Obviously there might be many reasons for this error, but maybe it helps someone...

Answer (score 0):

do a `npm install` after adding vuetify as `vue add vuetify` then start server by
`npm run serve`

Answer (score 0):

In your `package.json`: move `@nuxtjs/vuetify` from `devDependencies` to `dependencies`

Answer (score 0):

**just install the pacakge to devDependencies:**

```
npm i --save-dev vue-loader-v16
```

**After installing the dev dependency**

```
npm run serve
```