# Is there correct Getting Started documentation?

Tags: vuetify.js

I try to include Vuetify into an existing Vue project following step by step the guide:

[Vuetify quick-start existing-applications](https://next.vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/quick-start#existing-applications)

Vuetify styles are not visible. This is possible duplicate but is has no answer: [Vuetify Styles not visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51218758/vuetify-styles-not-visible)

How to make Vuetify styles work correctly?

Github Vuetify account has 500+ opened issues. Maybe this one is already reported somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After an investigation I found the Vuetify is so buggy, I wondered why developers use it!

Finally I created new application following the [official guide](https://next.vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/quick-start#new-applications) 
which is also [buggy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56406193/11586099). Then I move all my functionality to the new app.

Anyway I was able to set up empty Vuetify template.
Please avoid using Vuetify if you hasn't started yet. It will be pain in your brain!

**Update:**

Vuetify do not have possibility to contact support. That was a reason I created my question on Stackoverflow! Do not be offended please Vuetify is fit only for coding experts who use to survive without documentation and support. If you are beginner be aware.

Comment: There are many applications in production using Vuetify, you having troubles setting it up doesn't mean it's not good.

The amount of issues reported on the Github repo might have to do with how many people are using it ;). You understand that you can put a highly buggy package on Github... but if no one uses it... nobody will ad an issue to the repo.

Comment: I just checked you linked stackoverflow answer... Calling a very usefull library like vuetify buggy because you did not know that you had to run `npm install` after installing a new package is not right.

Comment: if you need help, you need to share you App.vue, Main.vue or whatever the entry component of you app is :)